# PHP GoDaddy VPS Not Error Reporting

Tags: php, reporting, error-log

BEFORE YOU MARK THIS A DUPLICATE READ PLEASE

I've read dozens of threads both on this site and other with possible solutions to my problem however none have helped.

I switched to a GoDaddy VPS and I cannot get php to log errors what so ever. I went to their chat support and they basically told me I was on my own. My current php.ini settings below.

- error_reporting = E_ALL
- display_startup_errors = On
- log_errors = On
- track_errors = On
- error_log = error_log
- display_errors = On

Current php version I have installed php 7.0 and the extensions that are installed below. (Not sure if this info is beneficial)

- php70-libc-client I
- php70-pear
- php70-php-bcmath
- php70-php-calendar
- php70-php-cli
- php70-php-ftp
- php70-php-fpm
- php70-php-devel
- php70-php-curl
- php70-php-common
- php70-php-gd
- php70-php-imap
- php70-php-mcrypt
- php70-php-mysqlnd
- php70-php-pdo
- php70-php-posix
- php70-runtime
- php70-php-xml
- php70-php-sockets

More Information (might be useful)
- I restarted my server multiple times.
- Using mysqli as data storage.

Error Logs That Exist
- /usr/local/cpanel/logs/error_log /usr/local/apache.ea3/logs/error_log
- /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear/error_log
- /var/installatron/logs/error_log /var/log/httpd/error_log
- /var/log/apache2/error_log /home/server1/public_html/css/error_log
- /home/server1/public_html/php/error_log
- /home/server1/public_html/contact/error_log /home/server1/.trash/error_log
- /home/server2/public_html/error_log /home/server2/public_html/php/error_log
- /home/server2/public_html/faq/error_log

which one would be the main one?

With the help of Max (below) I found some error logs.

```
[Tue Nov 29 14:58:23.876535 2016] [:notice] [pid 1072] ModSecurity: APR compile$
[Tue Nov 29 14:58:23.876543 2016] [:notice] [pid 1072] ModSecurity: PCRE compil$
[Tue Nov 29 14:58:23.876548 2016] [:notice] [pid 1072] ModSecurity: LUA compile$
[Tue Nov 29 14:58:23.876552 2016] [:notice] [pid 1072] ModSecurity: LIBXML comp$
[Tue Nov 29 14:58:23.876555 2016] [:notice] [pid 1072] ModSecurity: Status engi$
[Tue Nov 29 14:58:23.901172 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1073] AH01909: s104-238-126-2$
[Tue Nov 29 14:58:23.902445 2016] [:notice] [pid 1073] mod_ruid2/0.9.8 enabled
[Tue Nov 29 14:58:23.905483 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1073] AH00163: Apac$
[Tue Nov 29 14:58:23.905502 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1073] AH00094: Command lin$
(XID sda356) Database Connect Error: Access denied for user 'leechprotect'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: By 'cannot get PHP to log', do you mean that your PHP doesn't display any errors, or do you expect a log file or something ?

Comment: @Max I mean my php doesn't shoot out any error logs saying you have an error on line so and so. I used to get error_log file show up in the directory that the file with the php errors on it are however that doesn't happen anymore.

Comment: If you want to log the errors into a file, you must have this in your php.ini : `error_log = /var/log/my-errors.log`. Of course the path can be any existing file.

Comment: Did you restart your Apache server, anyway ?

Comment: @Max my error_log right now is error_log = error_log, and I restarted the entire VPS server so I would think that would also restart apache unless I'm wrong.

Comment: OK, so your file must be somewhere.. Try to find it with `find / -name error_log`

Comment: @Max Formatting really ugly, check the main thread.

Comment: Ok, I think the errors are inside `/var/log/httpd/error_log` or 
`/var/log/apache2/error_log`

Comment: Moreover you have other log files in your website structure, like `/home/server1/public_html/php/error_log`, you should check those

Comment: You should also have `display_errors = On` in your php.ini

Comment: @Max I added some error codes.

Comment: You may have an error with your database password : `'leechprotect'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`. And after adding `display_errors = On`, did you restart Apache ?

Comment: @Max It was already set to on, and I restarted the entire VPS multiple times? This would restart apache as well correct?

Comment: Yes, Apache is also restarted

Comment: Can you create a new PHP file and put `ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);`, and do something after that to make PHP throw an error ?

Comment: @Max Tried that, nothing different happen. I think my problems are coming from (XID sda356) Database Connect Error: Access denied for user 'leechprotect'@'localhost' (using password: YES). Looking into that now.